# Does Dapper support Enums?

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

I have a class User where Role is enum with values: Employee, Admin etc... Dapper throws an exception: "The member Role of type System.Enum cannot be used as a parameter value"

Does dapper support enums?

```
    IDbConnection connection
connection.Execute(sb.ToString(), entityToInsert, /*transaction: transaction*/tx, commandTimeout: commandTimeout);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enums are supported, but `Enum` isn't :p

So if you have:

```
class User {
    public MemberRole Role {get;set;}
}
```

then that should work fine; however

```
class User {
    public Enum Role {get;set;}
}
```

will not. Are you perhaps using the latter?

Comment: yes, I use the last one, but how the MemberRole should look then? MemberRole : enum  ... yes?

Comment: ah. I see what you mean. Thank you it works for me! You helped me a lot

Comment: @Sergey just `public enum MemberRole { Employee, Admin, ... }`. You should **never** typically use `Enum` - that is actually really inefficient. You should only use the typed enum.

Comment: @Sergey to be specific: a field of type `MemberRole` is *essentially* an `int` - 4 bytes per `User`. A field of type `Enum` is a *reference* to a boxed copy of a `MemberRole` - which is 4/8 bytes for the reference (x86/x64), plus the 8/16 bytes bytes for the object-header (x86/x64), plus the 4 bytes for the `MemberRole`, taking into account the *minimum object size* of 12/24 bytes - and all of a sudden instead of 4 bytes you've spent 16/32 bytes (x86/x64). Never use `Enum` unless you are using reflection. **AND** you've made unnecessary work for the garbage collector too!

Comment: Marc, what happens if the database returns a value that isn't a valid Enum member? For example, if the database returns a value like 159892, and there are only 2 entries of 0 and 1. Is an exception thrown?

Comment: @crush no, I think that is just cast successfully, the same as it would be in C# - i.e. `obj.Foo = (SomeEnum)reader.GetInt32(5);`

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks. I guess I can just use `Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), value)` to figure out if it's "invalid" after the fact. That's better than an exception being thrown anyways.